# Embed webform in facebook tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-tabs

I'm trying to embed a webform in facebook tab, using [Thunderpenny](http://www.thunderpenny.com/) - Website app. Had some issues with that.

How else can I achieve this, using other methods?

Any advise is most welcomed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As the message says, check your applications’s log files to find out what’s wrong. If you don’t have access to those, then asks Thunderpenny’s support.

Comment: @CBroe I already did that,got no replies.I'd appreciate recommendations to achieve this using another method.